# Javascript canvas rectangle animation not working

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, keyevent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script>
function draw() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");

// Rectangle position
var posX = 5;
var posY = 5;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect (posX, posY, 50, 50);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(key_press == "s") {
        posY += 3;
    }
 })
}
window.onload = draw;
</script>
<style>
#canvas1 {
    background: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone pls tell me why this is not working. When "s" is clicked. Increase posY's value by 3;
I have had this issue now for a long time. Does it have anything to do with the draw(); function?

I am not very good at javascript so i would really appreciate tips too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should update the drawing after change y value.And `key_press`  is uppercase `S` not `s`.
also you have to clear the previous drawing by calling `clearRect`

demo https://jsfiddle.net/3hgwp24m/1/ [updated]

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(key_press == "S") {//uppercase S not s
        posY += 3;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clear canvas
        ctx.fillRect (posX, posY, 50, 50);
    }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
       #canvas1 {
    background: #000000;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script>
var posX = 5;
var posY = 5;
function draw() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");

// Rectangle position
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect (posX, posY, 50, 50);

}
window.onload = draw;
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(key_press == "S") {
        posY += 3;
        draw();
    }
 })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```